# Without loop how to insert values into table from XML node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have the following requirement.

I have an XML variable of values.

I now should insert the values for this XML variable to a table (Table A), but need to check if the items (one by one) in the XML variable are already present in another table (Table B) and the count of that individual item present in table B is only once.

If more than once/ or not present in Table B, do not insert into the main table - Table A.

How to achieve this without using loops.

```
Declare @Names xml
set @Names ='<List><CNames>One</CNames><CNames>Two</CNames></List>'

**When used below xml variable of values become a column of values :**

SELECT tbl.colname.value('text()[1]','varchar(10)') AS CN
FROM @Names ('/List/CNames') tbl(colname);

CN
-------
One
Two
```

Now in Table B --  have to check if the items 'One' and 'Two' are present, if present are they present only once.

Tired using while loops which works fine, but want to achieve without loop.

Comment: In your example: do both values `One` and  `Two` have to be validated _together_? Is it OK to insert only `One` if it does not exist yet or must `One` and `Two` both not exist?

Comment: its one item vs one items validation and not One and Two together. So its ok to insert only "One" if it exists in another table, not bothering about the next value "Two".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a selection of your rows to evaluate (`@values` in my solution), I started from there.

**Sample data**

```
-- existing table and data
declare @data table
(
    CN nvarchar(10)
);
insert into @data (CN) values
('One'),
('Three'),
('Three');

-- new values extracted from XML
declare @values table
(
    CN nvarchar(10)
);
insert into @values (CN) values
('One'),    -- exists 1x and will be inserted
('Two'),    -- does not exist and will not be inserted
('Three');  -- exists 2x and will not be inserted
```

**Solution**

```
insert into @data (CN)
select v.CN
from @values v
cross apply (   select count(1) as 'Cnt'
                from @data d
                where d.CN = v.CN ) c
where c.Cnt = 1;
```

**Result**

```
select d.CN
from @data d
order by d.CN;


CN
----------
One
One      --> new inserted value
Three
Three
```